# How to find and Install driver for acher t9uh usb wifi adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet, usb-installation, ubuntu-drivers

I had a computer made without a WiFi card - if needed I can add one, but for now it has no WiFi capability.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it works fine.

I use my phone for a hotspot, I have no cable internet access.

I tried to plug my phone in to get internet through the USB but it doesn't work, the connection is recognised but does not connect.

I have a USB adapter - TP Link archer t9uh - I contacted TP Link and could not get any help from them to find the driver, or any info on how to install without an internet connection to the computer.

I have another PC running Ubuntu 20.04.

Ideally I'd like to save the driver to a USB and install it on the new computer.
I have 3 problems with this:

1. I don't know if this is possible
2. I cannot find a driver for the version of Ubuntu that I am running
3. I don't know how to install a driver on Ubuntu or if its possible on Ubuntu (I have updated and installed apps in terminal with copy and paste code successfully)

If there is no solution to this without installing a WiFi card I'll buy and install one. With this though, after all these issues, I'm also wondering if I should buy a specific WiFi card because I may have the same compatibility issue as the WiFi adapter.

Any instructions on how to find and install the driver from a USB would be greatly appreciated.

Or, tips on a WiFi card to install in the hard drive please.

Comment: The process to install a driver on Linux for the Archer t9uh is described in a document for which there is a link here https://www.tp-link.com/uk/support/download/archer-t9uh/. You might just need to take your machine somewhere where you can get a connection. Alternatively my experience is that usb dongles just work when you plug them in. Perhaps a friend might have one that you could try to get you going

Comment: Borrow an older USB wifi dongle from a friend. Many (not all) older 801.11n dongles just work. "Installing" a driver reaaly means *compiling* it, and the tools to compile --the build-essential package-- is not included in a new install of Ubumtu. It's a big download.

Comment: Thanks for the info @PonJar - I checked the link for t9uh, it only has them for windows and mac... but getting a dongle is a great tip that I hadn't considered, I'll hunt one down.

Comment: Thanks @PonJar I went to the link but it only has windows and PC drive links. A USB dongle is a great idea though, I'll check it out. Thank you

Comment: Cheers @user535733 , I'll look for an older dongle 801.11n...and it's helpful to understand about compiling drivers. Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, should have been more explicit. Near the top of the page are 3 links to manuals. The third link is for Linux installation. It describes how to compile the driver.